# Detect Collision between the Unity Starter Assets PlayerAmerture and other gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the Unity Starter Assets Third Person Controller and I have the PlayerAmerture in my scene and 4 tiles(floor) that was created with Probuilder. 2 of the tiles tag are safe tile, while the other two are danger tile.

I'm trying to check if PlayerAmerture is standing in the tile which the tag is danger tile, but I can't figure it out.

Here's what I tried: (this code is in the ThirdPersonController Script)

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    If(onExplision)
    {
        If(other.gameObject.CompareTag("danger tile"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
        }
    }
}
```

But somehow the code ain't working, please help me out.
Thank you

Comment: Are the capitalized 'If' a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't check the scene for you, but here is the trouble shooting guide with colliders:

1. Check if the collider has rigidbody
2. Check whether your tag is correct
3. Check if the objects are on the same layer(Scrap that, you have a 3D scene)

Those are the most common types of problems, but this should get you started.

P.S. Please refer from using tags in your project, they are heavy on performance, try using a reference to the class or interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Player doesn't have a rigidbody, just a CharacterController, is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks I already seen the problem, I was missing a sphere collider, the character controller just look like the sphere collider